# URL-Encoding a Byte String?

Tags: c++, windows, urlencode, sha1, bittorrent

I am writing a Bittorrent client. One of the steps involved requires that the program sends a HTTP GET request to the tracker containing an SHA1 hash of part of the torrent file. I have used Fiddler2 to intercept the request sent by Azureus to the tracker.

The hash that Azureus sends is URL-Encoded and looks like this: %D9%0C%3C%E3%94%18%F0%C5%D9%83X%E03I%26%2B%60%8C%BFR

The hash should look like this before it's URL-Encoded: d90c3ce39418f0c5d98358e03349262b608cbf52

I notice that it is not as simple as placing a '%' symbol every two characters, so how would I go about encoding this BYTE string to get the same as Azureus.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through the string from left to right. If you encounter a `%`, output the next two characters, converting upper-case to lower-case. If you encounter anything else, output the ASCII code for that character in hex using lower-case letters.

```
%D9 %0C %3C %E3 %94 %18 %F0 %C5 %D9 %83 X %E0 3 I %26 %2B %60 %8C %BF R
```

The ASCII code for X is 0x58, so that becomes `58`. The ASCII code for 3 is 0x33.

(I'm kind of puzzled why you had to ask though. Your question clearly shows that you recognized this as URL-Encoded.)

Comment: I think the question is about encoding, not decoding.

Comment: No difference. The process is clearly reversible. (And the **question** points out that it's just URL encoded!)

Comment: I hadn't realised that ascii characters could be used to represent the bytes, thank you for clearing that up! :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can just place a % symbol every two characters. Azureus doesn't do that because, for example, `R` is a safe character in a URL, and `52` is the hexadecimal representation of `R`, so it doesn't need to percent-encode it. Using  `%52` instead is equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I know well the original question was about C++, it might be useful somehow, sometimes to see alternative solutions. Therefore, for what it's worth (10 years later), here's

## An alternative solution implemented in Python 3.6+

```py
import binascii
import urllib.parse

def hex_str_to_esc_str(s: str, *, encoding: str='Windows-1252') -> str:
    # decode hex string as a Windows-1252 string
    win1252_str = binascii.unhexlify(hex_str).decode(encoding)
    # escape string and return
    return urllib.parse.quote(win1252_str, encoding=encoding)

def esc_str_to_hex_str(s: str, *, encoding: str='Windows-1252') -> str:
    # unescape the escaped string as a Windows-1252 string
    win1252_str = urllib.parse.unquote(esc_str, encoding='Windows-1252')
    # encode string, hexlify, and return
    return win1252_str.encode('Windows-1252').hex()
```

Two elementary tests:

```py
esc_str = '%D9%0C%3C%E3%94%18%F0%C5%D9%83X%E03I%26%2B%60%8C%BFR'
hex_str = 'd90c3ce39418f0c5d98358e03349262b608cbf52'

print(hex_str_to_esc_str(hex_str) == esc_str) # True
print(esc_str_to_hex_str(esc_str) == hex_str) # True
```

## Note

`Windows-1252` (aka `cp1252`) emerged as the default encoding as a result of the following test:

```py
import binascii
import chardet

esc_str = '%D9%0C%3C%E3%94%18%F0%C5%D9%83X%E03I%26%2B%60%8C%BFR'
hex_str = 'd90c3ce39418f0c5d98358e03349262b608cbf52'

print(
    chardet.detect(
        binascii.unhexlify(hex_str)
    )
)
```

...which gave a pretty strong clue:

```
{'encoding': 'Windows-1252', 'confidence': 0.73, 'language': ''}
```